# How to show a floating number with a fixed amount of digits in Qt?

Tags: qt

I want to display a floating number in Qt with a fixed amount of digits (4), but without filling non-used digits with zero (the equivalent of having a maximum number of digits). In other words, this is what I want to show for the following examples:

- 0 -> 0.0
- 10 -> 10.0
- 980.5 -> 980.5
- 1200.5 -> 1.200 k
- 9900.9 -> 9.900 k
- 120500.9 -> 120.5 k
- 999888.88 -> 999.9 k

etc.. I tried many combinations of both `QString::number()` as well as `QString::args()`, without success. So how can I do that?

Note: I'm aware that for numbers higher then 1000, I'll have to apply a division and add the label 'k' manually - I'm already doing that.

**EDIT:**
The following code does exactly what I want, only that it is quite inappropriate with all those `if else`. I would like to know how can I do that with Qt's functions:

```
float temp = getSomeValue();
const char* itemUnities[] = { "V", "W", "A", "J" };

if (temp < 10.0f)
{
    painter.drawText(defaultX + 60,yPosition,QString::number(temp,'f',3));
    painter.drawText(defaultX + 110,yPosition,tr(itemUnities[aaa]));
}
else if (temp < 100.0f)
{
    painter.drawText(defaultX + 60,yPosition,QString::number(temp,'f',2));
    painter.drawText(defaultX + 110,yPosition,tr(itemUnities[aaa]));
}
else if (temp < 1000.0f)
{
    painter.drawText(defaultX + 60,yPosition,QString::number(temp,'f',1));
    painter.drawText(defaultX + 110,yPosition,tr(itemUnities[aaa]));
}
else if (temp < 10000.0f)
{
    temp *= 0.001;

    painter.drawText(defaultX + 60,yPosition,QString::number(temp,'f',3));
    painter.drawText(defaultX + 110,yPosition,tr("k") + tr(itemUnities[aaa]));
}
else if (temp < 100000.0f)
{
    temp *= 0.001;

    painter.drawText(defaultX + 60,yPosition,QString::number(temp,'f',2));
    painter.drawText(defaultX + 110,yPosition,tr("k") + tr(itemUnities[aaa]));
}
else if (temp < 1000000.0f)
{
    temp *= 0.001;

    painter.drawText(defaultX + 60,yPosition,QString::number(temp,'f',1));
    painter.drawText(defaultX + 110,yPosition,tr("k") + tr(itemUnities[aaa]));
}
else if (temp < 10000000.0f)
{
    temp *= 0.000001;

    painter.drawText(defaultX + 60,yPosition,QString::number(temp,'f',3));
    painter.drawText(defaultX + 110,yPosition,tr("M") + tr(itemUnities[aaa]));
}
else if (temp < 100000000.0f)
{
    temp *= 0.000001;

    painter.drawText(defaultX + 60,yPosition,QString::number(temp,'f',2));
    painter.drawText(defaultX + 110,yPosition,tr("M") + tr(itemUnities[aaa]));
}
else if (temp < 1000000000.0f)
{
    temp *= 0.000001;

    painter.drawText(defaultX + 60,yPosition,QString::number(temp,'f',1));
    painter.drawText(defaultX + 110,yPosition,tr("M") + tr(itemUnities[aaa]));
}
```

Comment: where are you blocked?

Comment: @UmNyobe sorry, but I don't understand your question. :P

Comment: you have done quite a few things, but you dont say which use cases failed. Imho you have to transform the number into some floating point one and print it. How do you make `0` print `0.0`? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @UmNyobe Well I don't understand why should I write the codes that failed - after all what I want is the code that *works* for the scenario I presented \o/ In any case, I edited my question to post a code that does exactly what I want in a not so elegant way; I hope that helps.

Comment: Because just dumping a solution to be copy pasted is not helpful.

Comment: Factor out the actual formatting (without all that QPainter business) and your function is much simpler already. Then add a unit test to test it thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have very specific wishes for the conversion, a built in method does not provide all the functionality, but with some tricks, you can use `QString::number()` and `QString::truncate()`:

```
QString doubleToQStr(const double val, const size_t d)
{
  QString str = QString::number(val,'g',15);

  if( val >= std::pow(10.0,static_cast<double>(d-1)) ) 
  { 
    str.truncate(d); 

    // find magnitude
    size_t mag = 0;
    while( val >= std::pow( 10.0, static_cast<double>(mag) ) ) { mag++; } 

    if ( mag > 3 )
    {
      size_t dotpos = mag % 3;
      str.insert(dotpos,".");

      size_t mag3 = mag - dotpos;

      switch( mag3 )
      { 
      case 3:
        str += " k"; break;
      case 6:
        str += " M"; break;
      case 9:
        str += " G"; break;
      case 12:
        str += " T"; break;
      default:
        str += " ?"; break;
      }
    }
  }
  else if ( val < std::pow(10.0,static_cast<double>(-(static_cast<int>(d)-1))) )
  { str = "0.0"; }
  else
  { str.truncate(d+1); }  

  return str;
}
```

Here are the test cases I used:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  std::cout << "99919999.9 -> " << doubleToQStr(99919999.9, 4).toStdString() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "9999.9 -> " << doubleToQStr(9999.9, 4).toStdString() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "999.9 -> " << doubleToQStr(999.9, 4).toStdString() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "99.9 -> " << doubleToQStr(99.9, 4).toStdString() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "9.9 -> " << doubleToQStr(9.9, 4).toStdString() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "0.9 -> " << doubleToQStr(0.9, 4).toStdString() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "0.09 -> " << doubleToQStr(0.09, 4).toStdString() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "0.009 -> " << doubleToQStr(0.009, 4).toStdString() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "0.0009 -> " << doubleToQStr(0.0009, 4).toStdString() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "0.00009 -> " << doubleToQStr(0.00009, 4).toStdString() << std::endl;

    return a.exec();
}
```